When connecting to Google Cloud SQL DB, getCloudSqlConnection() connection error
I wrote the Connection syntax by referring to the URL below in Appscript.
<Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc?hl=ko#getcloudsqlconnectionurl>

I added the Google Chat service account ID to the IAM administrator of the Cloud SQL project and granted Cloud SQL client permissions.
I entered the correct values ​​for url, userName, and UserPassword, but I cannot connect with the following message.
Failed with an error

Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.



In the Cloud SQL IAM administrator menu, I added the Apps script account to the service account and granted Clous SQL Client permission.

Added https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice as oauthScopes in appsscript.json of apps script.

I have checked the Cloud SQL url, userName, and password multiple times and they are correct.



Could you try granting Clous SQL Owner/Admin permission( instead of client)?
